# Error MC3074: The tag 'WindowsFormsHost' does not exist in XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'

Tags: .net-core-3.0

I see Error MC3074: The tag 'WindowsFormsHost' does not exist in XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'.

My code below:
Wpf.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

and Window1.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfCs.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:wf="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms"        
    Title="WPF Demo" Height="500" Width="1000" Icon="/WpfCs;component/App.ico">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="250" />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <ToolBarTray Background="White" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <ToolBar Band="1" BandIndex="1">
                <Button Name="tbbOpen" Content="Open" Click="tbbOpen_Click">
                </Button>
                <Separator/>
                <Button Name="tbbPlay" Content="Play" Click="tbbPlay_Click">
                </Button>
                <Separator/>
                <Button Name="tbbStop" Content="Stop" Click="tbbStop_Click">
                </Button>
            </ToolBar>
        </ToolBarTray>

        <WindowsFormsHost Name="wfh" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" >
        </WindowsFormsHost>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

This code works under .Net Framework.
How to use WindowsFormsHost class in .Net Core 3.0 application?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your .csproj file has

```xml
<UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props-desktop

Answer (score -2):

You get the error: 
**The tag 'WindowsFormsHost' does not exist in XML namespace**, because the tag `WindowsFormsHost` isn't explained yet in XML namespace.

Comment: No. The tag 'WindowsFormsHost' is a part of 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation' namespace. I think a problem with xmlns:wf="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms" attribute